Python Backtrader Optstrategy results in AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'MA_strategy' on <module '__main__'
I try to use the backtrder Optstrategy to choose the best MA_period for the MA strategy, but meet the following error:
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'MA_strategy' on <module 'main' (<class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>)>
The bulk of the code is as follows:
import backtrader as bt
import backtrader.analyzers as btanalyzers
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
from datetime import datetime

# creat the strategy
class MA_strategy(bt.Strategy):
    
    params = dict(MA_period = 20)
    
 
    def __init__(self):
 
        self.order = None
       
        self.SMA = bt.indicators.MovingAverageSimple(period = self.params.MA_period)
   
         
    def next(self):
        
        if self.order: 
            return
        
        if not self.position:
            if self.data.close[0] > self.SMA[0]:
                self.order = self.buy()
            
        else:
            if self.data.close[0] < self.SMA[0]: 
                self.order = self.sell()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cerebro = bt.Cerebro()
    
    #cerebro.addstrategy(MA_strategy, MA_period = 20)
    
    cerebro.optstrategy(MA_strategy, MA_period = range(10,12))
    
    stock_OHLC = pd.read_csv("F:\pythonProject\quant\kline\HK.00700_kline.csv",index_col='time_key',parse_dates = True)
    start_date = datetime(2022, 12, 30)  # the start time of backtest
    end_date = datetime(2023, 12, 30)  # the end time of backtest
    data = bt.feeds.PandasData(dataname = stock_OHLC, fromdate= start_date, todate=end_date)  # load the data
    cerebro.adddata(data)  
    
    cerebro.broker.setcash(100000.0) 
    cerebro.addsizer(bt.sizers.FixedSize, stake=10)
  
    
    result = cerebro.run()
  
    
    cerebro.plot()

The code with function cerebro.addstrategy() works well.
